# VBA - Delete either row above or row below

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have an Excel sheet with the following structure:

What I need to do is delete an entire record if either it's Type A or Type B are = 0. As an example, for record 1, I need to delete A & B because B = 0.

[image]

I have the following code:

```
  Sub Loop_Example()
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


With ActiveSheet


    .Select


    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        With .Cells(Lrow, "B")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Therefore, what I would like to do is add the logic to delete the entire row if the value is 0 and either the row above or below depending on its 'type'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
Sub pDeleteRow()

        Dim wksData             As Worksheet
        Dim rngCell             As Range

        Dim lngCounter          As Long
        Dim lngTotalCount       As Long

        Set wksData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lngTotalCount = wksData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        lngCounter = 1

        With wksData
            While lngCounter <= lngTotalCount
                If (UCase(Trim(.Cells(lngCounter, 2))) = "A" Or UCase(Trim(.Cells(lngCounter, 2))) = "B") And UCase(Trim(.Cells(lngCounter, 3))) = "0" Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    lngCounter = lngCounter - 1
                    lngTotalCount = lngTotalCount - 1
                End If
                lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            Wend
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:

```
Sub ConditionalRowDelete()

Set colA = Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
Set colB = Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
MsgBox colA.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To colA.Rows.Count
If colB(i) = 0 Then
If colA(i) = "A" Then
'colB(i).Select
With colB(i) 'Selection
Application.Union(.EntireRow, .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow).Delete 'Select
End With
'Selection.EntireRow.Select
'MsgBox "found A"
End If
If colA(i) = "B" Then
'colB(i).Select
With colB(i) 'Selection
Application.Union(.EntireRow, .Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow).Delete 'Select
End With

'MsgBox "found B"
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```